# Error tratando de cargar una imagen con sdl2_image y c++,(segmentation faul core dumped)

Tags: c++

He tratado de cargar una imagen en `sdl2` y justamente cuando uso `sdl_image` obtengo un error (`segmeentation fault core dumped`). Solo ahí me da error todo lo demas parece funcionar bien.

Estas son la librerias correspondientes a `sdl2`

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL_events.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

Estas son las librerias correspondientes a c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

SDL_Window   *ventana; // declaracion de una variable para LA VENTANA
SDL_Renderer *render;  // declaracion de una variable para RENDERIZAR
SDL_Texture  *textura; // declaracion de una variable para TEXTURA
SDL_Surface  *img;     // declaracion de una SUPERFICIE PARA LA IMAGEN

int main()  {

  // AQUI SE CREA UNA VENTANA DE 640 POR 480 LLAMADA "PRUEBA"   
  ventana = SDL_CreateWindow("prueba",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640,480,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

  // AQUI SE COMPRUEBA SI LA VENTANA ES CREADA CORRECTAMENTE
  if(ventana==NULL)
  {
    printf("error en ventana %s\n",SDL_GetError());
  }
  else
  {
    // SI LA VENTANA SE CREA CORRECTAMENTE SE HACE EL RENDERIZADO
    render=SDL_CreateRenderer(ventana,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if(render==NULL)
    {
      printf("error en render %s\n",SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
      // SI EL RENDERIZADO TIENE EXITO SE CREA UN COLOR PARA EL RENDERIZADO
     SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff);

     // SE INICIA SDL2_IMAGE PARA CARGAR UNA IMAGEN FORMATO PNG 
     int flag=IMG_INIT_PNG;
     if(!(IMG_Init(flag)&flag))
     {
       printf("error en imginit %s\n",IMG_GetError());
     }
     else
     {
       // SI SE TIENE EXITO INICIANDO SDL2_IMAGE SE PROCEDE A CARGAR
       // LA IMAGEN
       // JUSTO AQUI OCURRE EL ERROR SOLO COLAPSA SIN ARROJAR MENSAJE
       // DE  ERROR NI NADA
       // SOLO UN SEGMENTATION FAULT CORE DUMP SI COLOCO DOBLE SLASH A
       // ESTE FRACMENTO DE CODIGO EL CORE DUMP DESAPARECE Y SE CARGA LA
       // VENTANA CON EL COLOR BLANCO DE FONDO DEL RENDERIZADO ASI ME DI
       // CUENTA QUE EL ERROR SOLO ESTA EN ESTA LINEA
       img=IMG_Load("awesome_pot__x1_broken_png_1354830342.png");
       if(img==NULL)
       {
         printf("error en img load %s\n",IMG_GetError());
       }
       else
       {
         // DE CARGARSE CORRECTAMENTE LA IMAGEN SE PROCEDE A CREAR UNA
         // TEXTURA EN BASE A LA IMAGEN
         textura=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render,img);
         if(textura==NULL)
         {
           printf("error en textura %s\n",SDL_GetError());
         }
         else
         {
           // UNA VEZ UTILIZADA LA IMAGEN PARA CREAR LA TEXTURA ESTA
           // PUEDE SER ELIMINADA
           SDL_FreeSurface(img);

           // AQUI SE COLOCA EL RENDER DE COLOR BLANCO
           SDL_RenderClear(render);

           // AQUI ES DONDE SE COPIA EL RENDER Y LA TEXTURA EN PANTALLA
           // SIN MOSTRAR LA PANTALLA       
           SDL_RenderCopy(render,textura,NULL,NULL);

           // AQUI FINALMENTE SE MUESTRA LA IMAGEN EN PANTALLA
           SDL_RenderPresent(render);

           // ESTE ES UN RETRASO PARA QUE EL PROGRAMA CORRA POR 2
           // SEGUNDOS 
           SDL_Delay(2000);

           // FINALMENTE SE CIERRA SDL Y EL SDL_IMAGE
           IMG_Quit();
           SDL_Quit();

           // ESTAS LLAVES CORRESPONDEN A LAS SENTENCIAS IF DE ARRIBA
         }//render
       }//img_init
     }//imgload
   }//textura
 }//ventana
```

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta para que el código sea más legible?
Resulta complicado analizarlo como se está mostrando ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo arregle , me vi obligado  a reinstalar **sdl2 image** , al parecer algo salio mal al instalarlo.

La verdad ignoro que salio mal al instalarlo pero de alguna manera cuando lo instale por medio del **gestor de paquetes synaptic** algún error de instalación debió ocurrir.

para corregir el problema hice lo siguiente:

1. Descargue **sdl2_image** desde la pagina -> **https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/** y descargue el paquete de nombre -> **SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz.**

2.Ingrese a la terminal como super usuario y entre a la carpeta de descargas utilizando el comando **cd** .

3 Una vez en la carpeta de descargas ingrese a la carpeta de **sdl2_image y copie ./configure.**

4. Cuando finalizo la ejecucion de **./configure  ingrese el comando make all.**
5. Al finalizar **make all, ingrese el comando make install** . y listo problema resuelto.

De alguna manera instalarlo paso a paso corrigio el error generado despues de instalarlo por el gestor de paquetes .

Comment: Por favor indica más información sobre esto. ¿Pudiste detectar qué parte salió mal durante la instalación, algún módulo que debió ser re configurado quizás? Esta información hará que esta respuesta sea de mayor ayuda para futuros lectores.

Comment: voto positivo porque el usuario editó su respuesta.